# password for ssh sftp

Tags: ssh

I am doing sshbor sftp from root of a linux machine to connect to another remote linux machine. port 22 is open but it is asking for password. I ran ssh -vvv and got output .can someone here analyze it and let me know what needs to be done to disable the password authentication. thanks

Comment: Can you demonstrate your efforts at solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have ssh keys set up then all you need to do is, take the public ssh key from one server, and place it in the authorized key file of the remote host.

Your public ssh key will be somwhere like `/home/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

This key can be copied into the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host.

Or you can follow the below steps to create new keys and set up password-less ssh.

run:

```
ssh-keygen
```

This will create a public key somthing like this:

```
/home/myhome/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

You can then use `ssh-copy-id` to copy the public key to the remote host:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /home/myhome/.ssh/id_rsa.pub remote-host
```

This will add the newly created public key to the authorized keys file on the remote host.

You can check the new key was added by looking in:

```
.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now you will not be prompted for a password.

Answer (score 0):

perform a ssh key pair between the hosts

Example:
(hostA and hostB)

```
hostA# ssh-keygen
hostA# ssh-copy-id hostB
hostB# insert password of hostB
```

now is possible to use sftp without password

Comment: thanks all for your valuable suggestions. actually it solved by giving access to this drive by our IT team. thanks